# function to get an instance of a form

Tags: c#, forms, casting

I want to build an build a function that does return me an already existing instance of a form.

```
fx = getForm(Form1);
```

here i get the error 'FensterTest.Form1' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
So i need some casting, but i have no idea in what i need to cast.

```
private Form getForm(Form f)
{
  foreach (Form a in Application.OpenForms)
  {
    if (a is f)
    {
      f fx = (f)a;
      return fx;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

and wherever i use "f" i get a "type or namespace name 'f' not found"

"f fx = (f)a;" was formerly "Form1 fx = (Form1)a;" and that worked quite well, but since i do also need to use Form2 Form3, ...

Comment: Please clarify - do you want a _new_ instance of a form or an/the existing instance to be returned?

Comment: sorry, i do want to get an existing instance of a form.  with "fx = getForm(Form1);" i only want to say from what form the instance is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to find the `Form` from the `OpenForms` collection, that is of a specified type. So you need to pass the type in - you can either pass in a `Type` object, or you can make the method generic so you can pass in a type parameter. Sending in a type parameter has the advantage that you can be type safe (returning the concrete type that you searched for in case you need it). Here is a generic solution:

```
private TForm getForm<TForm>()
    where TForm : Form
{
    return (TForm)Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Note, `OfType` and `FirstOrDefault` is a LINQ extension methods, make sure you import System.Linq.
Use the method above like this:

```
Form f = getForm<Form1>();
```

Comment: you could add a `where TForm : Form`.

Comment: add `where TForm : Form` where and what does it do?

Comment: @ralph, `where TForm : Form` is a generic constraint, that ensures you can only pass in types that derives from Form. It would be an enhanced type safety ensuring that you cannot search for an unrelated type in the OpenForms collections (For instance, passing in `getForm<string>`, which doesn't make sense). I updated the code sample.